# Unable to set property in es6 inherited class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

My base class is here: [Game Object](https://github.com/ShashankaNataraj/snake/blob/master/app/scripts/GameObject.js)

```
class GameObject { // Represents any interactable object within the game, be it the snake or the food or the snake world itself
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0, width = 0, height = 0) {
    this._x = x;
    this._y = y;
    this._width = width;
    this._height = height;
  }

  get x() {
    return this._x;
  }

  set x(x) {
    this._x = x;
  }

  get y() {
    return this._y;
  }

  set y(y) {
    this._y = y;
  }

  get position() {
    return {
      x: this._x,
      y: this._y
    }
  }

  set position(pos) {
    this._x = pos.x;
    this._y = pos.y;
  }

  get width() {
    return this._width;
  }

  set width(width) {
    this._width = width;
  }

  get height() {
    return this._height;
  }

  set height(height) {
    this._height = height;
  }

  get dimensions() {
    return {
      width: this._width,
      height: this._height
    }
  }

  set dimensions(dimensions) {
    this._width = dimensions.width;
    this._height = dimensions.height;
  }
}
```

My child class is here: [Child class](https://github.com/ShashankaNataraj/snake/blob/master/app/scripts/Snake.js)

```
class Snake extends GameObject {
  constructor() {
    super.dimensions = {width: 3};
  }
}
```

The problem is when Babel runs through this code, it doesn't produce the constructor method in the final JS output. Im just trying to set the width of the snake in the snake classes constructor. I expect the width to be defined by the parent class.

Comment: Please post your code in your question, instead of only linking it.

Comment: Every child constructor needs to call `super()` in ES6. And you shouldn't set properties on `super`, but rather on `this`.

Comment: do you need to export your modules? so export GameObject so you can import and extend from it?

Comment: if you haven't done module exports yet http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html is one of my favorite run downs.

Comment: @Bergi Ah I see. I was trying to set this.width = 3, but that wasnt working. Havent tried calling super() though. Let me check!

Comment: @Bergi, Your suggestion works. Since you were the first one to suggest calling super(), I want to accept yours as the answer, Can you add your answer as an answer instead of a comment so I can accept it?

Comment: @shashankan: Actually I rather wonder why you did not get a compiler error because of that.

Comment: @Bergi I didnt get any errors on my gulp task. Maybe because the gulp plugin didnt bubble it up? Either way, the JS file which was being output from the task didnt have the relevant code with the entire sentence being trimmed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Snake extends GameObject {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.dimensions = {width: 3};
  }
}
```